# How can I wait until specified "xterm" finished?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

In my c-shell file, I did something like:

xterm -e "source xxxx0" &

xterm -e "source xxxx1" &

wait

code....

It works fine that code after "wait" will be executed after the two xterm finished.

But it also gives problem. If I have some ps open, like an txt file opened by geditn, or I have an eclipse open, it will hung there since "wait" is waiting for all jobs to be finished.

So how can I let "wait" only wait for those two xterm jobs.

Or in another word, I want those two "xterm" run concurrently. And after they both done, the code can be continued. How shall I do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Google for `bash job control` and read [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 2):

Tell `wait` the process ids it should wait for:

```
xterm ... &
pid1=$!

xterm ... &
pid2=$!

wait $pid1 $pid2
```

That's assuming you use a shell where `wait` supports multiple arguments (bash,zsh, ...). If you use sh for portability, then you have to do two waits:

```
wait $pid1
wait $pid2
```

This will wait untill both are finished. If the second finishes before the first, the wait  will  immediately return.

Comment: Hi @ahilsend, I found if I use the PID number directly, it works, like:
wait $20234

Well if I save the number like:
sleep 20 &
set pid1=$!
sleep 30 &
set pid2=$!
wait $pid1 $pid2

It says wait: Too many arguments

Comment: bash supports to wait for multiple pids. Are you using sh? If it doesn't have to be very portable then change to bash. Otherwise do two commands: `wait $pid1; wait $pid2;`This will wait till both are finished. If the second finishes before the first it will give you a message that it's not a child, but immediately return.

Comment: Well, i am using C Shell.Since this works for me:

wait $20234   (20234 is a PID I got from the console for sleep 30 &)

Well when I save it like "pid1 = $!"
I guess I shall use "wait $($pid1)"

but $($pid1) is not allowed, it should be easy to make it right?

Comment: wait $19601 $19602 also fine for me.

Comment: I see, never used c shell. In that case try \$$pid1.

Comment: :( no, \$$pid1 not working. I'll try to google it. Thanks a lot for your kind help