# wait for two PID in c-shell

Tags: linux, shell, pid, csh

Following works for me:

```
>sleep 20 &
[1] 30414
>sleep 30 &
[2] 30415
>wait $30414 $30415
```

This works all right until I want to write this into tmp.csh

In my tem.csh file

```
sleep 20 &
set pid1=$!
sleep 30 &
set pid2=$!
```

When it comes to "wait"

```
wait $pid1 $pid2 => too many arguments
wait $pid1 => too many arguments
wait \$$pid1 => too many arguments
wait $($pid1) => Illegal variable name
```

How shall I write it?

And this question is for a solution of 
[How can I wait until specified "xterm" finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101731/how-can-i-wait-until-specified-xterm-finished)

Comment: **Avoid using the C-shell**. Read [C shell considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Try `zsh` or `bash` or `fish` shell instead. Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: Notice that `$30414` is expanded to empty! Try your `wait`  command prefixed by `echo` to be sure....

Comment: echo $pid1
echo $pid2
gives correct number. I guess it is my grammer error for $($pid1) ?

Comment: Really switch to a more modern shell. As you can see, nobody is answering because we all have forgotten *C-shell* (I did use it in the 1990s on Sun4/110 workstations).

Comment: Not everyone has the luxury of choosing the shell to use.  I have to use csh at work (in my scripting as well) because we have some tools that don't play well with bash.  I think it's save to assume the OP is using csh because they have to... like Fortran, you wouldn't pick it up for fun.

Comment: To the OP's original question, it appears that `wait` doesn't accept any arguments in `csh`.  As Basile points out, `$30414` expands to an empty string because that variable is not declared.  `wait` appears to wait for all jobs in the background to finish.  You might be able to just call `wait`, no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The "wait" command will not wait for specific PIDs. Try the following in CSH to wait for specific PIDs:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

sleep 30 &
set pid1 = $!
sleep 40 &
set pid2 = $!

while ( `ps -p "$pid1,$pid2" | wc -l` > 1 )
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in tcsh:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

time
sleep 10 &
sleep 5 &
wait
time
```

It looks like that wait doesn't take any argument, just waits until every backgorunded process finish.