# How does while loop wait for the process

Tags: linux, shell, pid, csh

With reference to [wait for two PID in c-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104195/wait-for-two-pid-in-c-shell)

In

```
while ( `ps -p "$pid1,$pid2" | wc -l` > 1 )
  sleep 1
end
```

what is the expression `ps -p "$pid1,$pid2" | wc -l > 1` doing?

Answer (score 0):

It simply checks if there are any processes matching *at least one* of the given `pid1` or `pid2`.

Just do your own quick check with PIDs 1 and 2:

```
  $ ps -p "1,2" # Show all processes with PID=1 and PID=2
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:57 systemd
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
```

The output has three lines, as a pipe to `wc -l` will also tell you. So as long as you have more than a line (the header is always there), your loop will be executed.